# use get_option in external php file

Tags: php, wordpress

i create a simple wordpress plugin and wanna use get_option() in my external php file
i know that i can use this to codes to include wp-load.php and use get_option()

```
require_once('../../../wp-load.php');
```

but i wanna include wp-load.php in correct way
also i read http://ottopress.com/2010/dont-include-wp-load-please/ and coulnt find a solution

Comment: **external php file**? Did you mean, like your php file is not in wordpress directory? Or something else?

Comment: i mean it's in my plugin directory like custom_php_file.php , i wanna use wordpress function on this page like get_option or wp_die or something else ...

Comment: then you don't have to include wp-load.php in your plugin directory. Take a look on the answer to know in more details.

Answer (score 0):

"Options" is a WordPress database table. You can use [get_option()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option) from your plugin, assuming it's installed, without manually loading *wp-load.php*.

```
<?php echo get_option( 'option_name' ); ?>
```

Comment: i also use wp_die in the page , so what should i do ?

Answer (score 0):

wordpres has the following structure with 3 directories and few files:

```
- /wp-admin
- /wp-content
- /wp-includes
- /files...
```

All your plugin and themes are located in `wp-content` directory. For all your plugin or themes files you don't need to include any extra files to use there default functions or hooks.

But in case you have extenal directory or files that is not part of the wordpress structure and you want to access the wordpress functionality then in this case you have to include the `wp-load.php` file. Take a look on this structure:

```
// Directory example
- /external_dir (Not part of WordPress Structure)
or
// File example
- /my_custom_file.php (Not part of WordPress Structure)

- /wp-admin
- /wp-content
- /wp-includes
- /files...
```

Answer (score 0):

Below file does not need to include when you are coding in your theme folder or developing any plugin because all wordpress function and libraries are called by default.
You need to include when you are coding outside the wordpress structure i.e "wp-content" folder.

If the page you are trying to execute is reside in the same directory, use

require('./wp-blog-header.php');

If the page is not in the same directory, use

require('/the/path/to/this/wp-blog-header.php');